# Technical difference between a Forward and a Reply

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

What is the technical difference between a forward and reply?

Are the headers handled differently?

I am curious about this because I have an issue with a bespoke outlook add-in that only occurs when forwarding an email.

Comment: Forwarding should completely replace the header, instead of modifying it the way a reply does. for instance, when I report spam in my organization, I create a new email and attach the prior email, rather than forwarding it, so that the original emails header is completely preserved. if I forwarded the message, the header info our admins want would be lost.

Comment: I tend to use copy/paste rather than forward, but you can begin by viewing the headers if you have a question re the headers

Comment: One of the biggest differences is that in a reply any attachments are lost, whereas when a message is forwarded, attachments stay with the email.